# cargo sqlx prepare produces stub file -- even with 'offline' feature enabled

Tags: rust, rust-sqlx

I am using some sqlx::query! and sqlx::query_as! and my project compiles fine.  But when I run cargo sqlx prepare I get first and error:

```
$ cargo sqlx prepare
error: extra arguments to `rustc` can only be passed to one target, consider filtering
the package by passing, e.g., `--lib` or `--bin NAME` to specify a single target
error: `cargo check` failed with status: exit status: 101
```

Then when I run it with "-- --lib" I get:

```
$ cargo sqlx prepare -- --lib
   Compiling crate v0.1.0 (/Users/ryan/Documents/crate)
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 5.78s
warning: no queries found; please ensure that the `offline` feature is enabled in sqlx
query data written to `sqlx-data.json` in the current directory; please check this into version control
```

I get similar output with --bin.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I also had the same issue. I guess there's some bug. I fixed it by running `cargo clean` and then running `cargo sqlx prepare -- --bin <bin_name>`

Comment: `cargo clean` didn't work for me, I had to reinstall with `cargo install sqlx-cli --no-default-features --features native-tls,postgres`, then it worked as `cargo sqlx prepare`.

Comment: Also, make sure, that you using same version of `sqlx-cli` and `sqlx`, that you pointed as dependency of you package.

Answer (score 6):

Same case had before, but could find usefull information in their [documentation](https://docs.rs/sqlx/latest/sqlx/macro.query.html#offline-mode-requires-the-offline-feature). Rather than running only `cargo sqlx prepare -- --lib`, first reinstall sqlx-cli, like below:

```
cargo install sqlx-cli && cargo sqlx prepare -- --lib
```

Comment: having an old version of sqlx-cli installed may result in `query!`-macros are not extracted from the code, just saying like "did you switch the 'offline' feature on"? So `cargo install sqlx-cli` did it for me.